# html5 offline cache, not working with some dynamic content that uses htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, offline

Im trying to make offline verison of page, but dynamically generated pages are not caching.

When I restart browser and turn on offline mode i cant access search.html(it is dynamic content page, created by YII Framework)

but i can access all statics files like css and js.

Things i have:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteRule ^admin admin.php
```

**cache.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST


CACHE:

/
/search.html
/index.php
/css/screen.css
/css/print.css
/css/main.css
/css/form.css
/assets/aa1d1537/jquery/css/redmond/jquery-ui.css
/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css
/assets/6e74162b/jquery.js
/js/main.js
/images/spacer.gif
/js/lightbox/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js
/js/lightbox/init.js
```

manifest in html tag

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" manifest="/cache.manifest">
```

any ideas whats should i do?

Comment: are you sure you are not adding a queriestring to search.html. Like /search.html?q=question. What happens if you (temporarily) create a static search.html file?

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess you already checked that, otherwise you won't be able to see css etc. but did you configure your apache server (if you're using this one) to serve the manifest corectly?

For example add a .htaccess file with the folowing content

`AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest`

Answer (score -1):

Send some caching information with the dynamically generated pages.

e.g. see [this page](http://www.badpenguin.org/php-howto-control-page-caching) (except for the bit about HTTPS - which is completely wrong)

Comment: This link has nothing to do with HTML5 Offline storage, it's about php caching techniques...